# When I run the project I use the native warning: ViewPager Android has been extracted from react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-viewpager

When I run my project it comes warning: ViewPagerAndroid has been extracted?

I'm looking for Open Issue Github and Stackoverflow

`Warning: ViewPagerAndroid has been extracted from react-native`

I expect to eliminate this warning.

Comment: Hi Zidniryi. I'm not sure what you're getting at. Is there some code you want us to look at? If so please put it into the question. Have a look at [ask] for more information on asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager instead of `import {ViewPagerAndroid} from 'react-native';`